# What are the values for constants LVCFMT_LEFT, LVCFMT_RIGHT and LVCFMT_CENTER?

Tags: c#, listview, interop, sendmessage

I am using a ListView in C# and am customizing it and need to make calls using interop to SendMessage() to add a sort indicator. I have found various articles, but in my case the left and right alignments are getting messed up.

I see references to LVCFMT_LEFT, LVCFMT_RIGHT and LVCFMT_CENTER in sample C++ code.

What are the values these constants? I have not been able to find these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear to be

```
#define LVCFMT_LEFT                 0x0000 // Same as HDF_LEFT
#define LVCFMT_RIGHT                0x0001 // Same as HDF_RIGHT
#define LVCFMT_CENTER               0x0002 // Same as HDF_CENTER
```

These are discoverable in CommCtrl.h which should be on your machine somewhere.  The first one I found on my machine is in `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\`